# Kile on a new windows computer -- Quickbuild -> "Failed to start"

Tags: kile, live-preview

I've just installed Kile on my new windows computer, perfectly according to the instructions and exactly like I did on my previous computer.

Now I get the following error as soon as I open a file: "[LivePreview-PDFLaTeX] Failed to start". The warning given with it is: "cannot open log file, did you run LaTeX?"

I've looked on the internet for the same error and the supposed answer I get is completely irrelevant (Settings-Kile-Tools-Okular, I've got Okular installed and the settings are already what I'm instructed to chance them to).

Why does it suddenly refuse to do anything outright? Hope you guys can help because I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: kile is an editor, but have you installed tex?

Comment: I'm guessing David's comment will resolve this. If not, in Kile, try using the menu option `Settings` > `System Check...` to identify what Kile thinks it can and cannot find on your system. Some warnings here are not critical - they tell you that Kile can't find optional software. But some are critical - they tell you that Kile cannot find essential software.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Somehow I missed the link to tex on the same webpage as the Kile install instructions. Anyway, I now have a different problem so I'm going to do some more internet searching. This one has been resolved.